# nodejs .env variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server

I am getting undefined when trying to get the value from .env

Here is my server.js

```
 console.log(process.env.val);
```

Here is my .env file

```
 val=hello
```

[Screenshot that shows the file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1kzC.png)

When I run the server I get undefined. How to fix?

Comment: Your `.env` file has to be in the root folder of your project if you're loading it via the `dotenv` package.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev works now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) library

Create a ***.env*** file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of ***NAME=VALUE***. For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
That's it.
```

***process.env*** now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file.

```
var db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```